# Что происходит в этом куске HandleChange | React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Объясните что происходит в это куске кода пошагово. Долго сидел пытался понять, но так и не понял.

По туториалу изучаю множественный ввод формы в ReactJS. В туториале есть следующий кусок кода:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputs(values => ({...values, [name]: value}))
}
```

1. Что такое `event.target.name` и `event.target.value`, может ли вместо **name** и/или **value** быть другие названия в зависимости от того что происходит в `render() {return (...);}`, то есть если у меня в форме не **name** а, к примеру, **samplename**

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    name="samplename" 
    placeholder='Name'
    value={inputs.username || ""} 
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

2. Что такое **Arrow function** я знаю, и что при возвращении литерального выражения его нужно брать в скобки, но не совсем понимаю что происходит в к фигурных скобках, а конкретнее,

```
({...values, [name]: value})
```

Почему **name** в квадраных скобках, и почему ему присваивается **value**?

3. Если я хочу дальше использовать полученные данные из формы, как мне это сделать?

Приложу код всей функции:

```
function MultipleInputs() {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;
        setInputs(values => ({...values, [name]: value}))
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        alert(inputs);
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
            Enter your name:
            <input 
                type="text" 
                name="username" 
                placeholder='Name'
                value={inputs.username || ""} 
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
            Enter your surname:
            <input 
                type="text"
                placeholder="Surname"
                name="surname"
                value={inputs.surname || ""}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    );
}

const MFRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#MFRoot"));
MFRoot.render(<MultipleInputs />);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`event.target.name` и `event.target.value`.**

Event.target возвращает конкретный элемент на котором случилось событие. Свойства `name` и  `value` берутся у соответственно у самого этого элемента. Value отвечает за значение внутри поля input, а свойство `name` за атрибут name (у первого input это username, а у второго это surname).

**Что происходит в скобках?**

Внутри скобок разворачивается старый state и добавляется новое поле (или перезаписывается) с названием таким же как у name, а значение для этого поля будет получено у value.

Пример:

```js
const obj = {
  username:'123',
  surname:'PPP'
}
console.log({...obj,username:'321'})
```

**Зачем name в квадратных скобках?**

Для того чтобы у поля называлось именно как значение у переменной name, а не добавлялось новое поле name.

Пример:

```js
let name = "username"
let value = '123'
const obj1 = {name:value}
console.log(obj1)
const obj2 = {[name]:value}
console.log(obj2)
```

**Использование полученных данных из формы.**

Не совсем понятен вопрос. Но могу предположить что вы про это.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const {username,surname}= inputs
        alert(`username:${username} ; surname:${surname}`);
    }
```

Comment: вопрос Вы поняли последний правильно. Большое Вам спасибо за объяснение.